# Is it possible to identify outstanding ssl certificates?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, certificate-revocation

Is it possible to identify what certificate authorities has put out valid certificates for a given domain?
For example, if my server leaves my control for some period of time is it possible to determine if it was registered with some CA that I would not know about (and therefore determine if some third party has access to a valid private key that I do not know about).

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to find out if all existing CA's have issued a certificate for a specific domain. But, it is possible to get this information for many of the public CA's which are included by default as trusted into the browsers/OS because these CA publish newly issued certificates into public accessible certificate logs. These logs then can be monitored and also searched by others, for example using [the interface provided by google](https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/https/ct/).

While not all public CA currently publish such logs it looks like that Google Chrome will require this for all public CA's included in [Chrome until October 2017](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/ct-policy/78N3SMcqUGw/ykIwHXuqAQAJ).

For more information about the idea behind these logs and how they work in detail see the [certificate transparency website](https://www.certificate-transparency.org/).

Comment: +1 for a service I did not know (per my comment to Lukas' answer). It is good to see that Chrome has actually a deadline for the check.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** - that's what [Certificate Transparency](https://www.certificate-transparency.org/what-is-ct) is trying to archive.

> Certificate Transparency aims to remedy these certificate-based
>   threats by making the issuance and existence of SSL certificates open
>   to scrutiny by domain owners, CAs, and domain users. Specifically,
>   Certificate Transparency has three main goals:
>
> - Make it impossible (or at least very difficult) for a CA to issue a SSL certificate for a domain without the certificate being visible
>     to the owner of that domain.
> - Provide an open auditing and monitoring system that lets any domain owner or CA determine whether certificates have been mistakenly
>     or maliciously issued.
> - Protect users (as much as possible) from being duped by certificates that were mistakenly or maliciously issued.
>
> ([Source](https://www.certificate-transparency.org/what-is-ct))

This means that you as a domain owner can query which certificates were issued. You can query these logs for example at https://crt.sh/ . This is how it looks like for example.com:

---

[image: Certificate Logs from example.com]

---

Please note that this only works for Certificate Authoriries that provide "*Certificate Transparency Logs*". Google however ...

> *[...] encourages all CAs to write the certificates they issue to
>   publicly verifiable, append-only, tamper-proof logs. In the future,
>   Chrome and other browsers may decide not to accept certificates that
>   have not been written to such logs.* ([Source](https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/https/ct/?hl=en))

Comment: This is a very useful service, thanks. **I think this kind of answer should be the accepted answer** (yours or Stephen's)  as it exactly answers the OP concern (provided that it is used widely enough, but your last sentence shows that this will hopefully happen soon when the Chrome Whip comes into play :)). I will leave my answer for the general "not a problem, though" perspective.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not, but this is not a problem (if I correctly understood your concern).

In order for the CA to issue you a certificate, you need to generate a certificate request which is bound to the web server. You then get a certificate you can install on this server, and not on another.

If you did not have control of the web server and now you do, just check which TLS certificates are configured for the server (or various virtual hosts). If they are all yours then you are fine - even if someone had a certificate it cannot be used anywhere else.

The case is a bit more complicated for a wildcard certificate - it now depends whether other people can install virtual hosts on it or not.

Comment: The certificate is not bound to specific server (hardware) but to a host name (or multiple names). Anybody having the private key for the certificate can create a server which uses this certificate. Notably an attacker which gets access to this certificate and private key or can create a matching certificate trusted by a public CA can use this certificate to impersonate the original server inside a man in the middle attack. Thus it is actually dangerous if somebody can create such a certificate.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: OP has a server (which I assume being a web server, per my answer). Say `www.example.com`. This is technically served by a web engine/server (Apache, ...) which has in its configuration the fact that `www.example.com` uses `cert1` (this is several files, but that does snot matter for the question). OP looses contact with the server, comes back and is in control of the configuration of `www.example.com`. No matter what happened (including another cert being issued for `www.example.com`, if his `cert1` is still in the config there is no problem.

Comment: (cont'd). I also assume that OP has control over the DNS pointing to `www.example.com`

Comment: If user looses control over the server an attacker might use the gained access to get a new certificate for this server without installing it on the server. This certificate could then be used to impersonate the server within a man in the middle attack.

Comment: OP mentiones that the server "leaves my control", which I interpret as "someone else was taking care of it". In any case the MitM attack needs the DNS to be modified. If the DNS is changed to point to another machine, a cert is issued for that other machine and that other machines works as an intermediate, and the vhost entries on the OP's machine is changed then yes, this is possible. I am not sure that this was the core of the question (but OP may clarify)

Comment: A MITM attack against the local network does not need control of DNS, ARP spoofing is enough. For a MITM attack against a wider network control of DNS might  of useful but even then it does not need control of the authoritative DNS for the domain but only of the DNS servers used as recursive DNS in the attacked network. And no administrator of a domain is in control of all DNS servers in the world which might be used for lookups regarding this domain.